# Problems with footer size using KOMA (scrlayer-scrpage)

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrbook, scrlayer-scrpage

I want to generate a document (`scrbook`) with a header including the section title and page number, and without anything in the footer. The generation of this header isn't a problem, but it's very high on the page, while there is *a lot* of white space for the empty footer.
I am aware that my use of `DVI=12` influences especially the position of the header line, but reducing this results in margins that seem very wide - and still a huge footer area. Is there any way to adjust the heights of header and footer to get more space for the header and less for the footer? I'm not sure where to put the `headheight` option, as it doesn't seem to do anything when in the `\documentclass[]`, which was the only example I could find.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, BCOR=15mm, 11pt, numbers=noenddot, DIV=12]{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

% changing headers and footers
\usepackage[automark, headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ihead{\headmark}
\ohead{\pagemark}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loading the scrbook-class with the option `headinclude=true` (and eventually `footinclude=true`) may help:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, headinclude=true, footinclude=true, twoside, BCOR=15mm, 11pt, numbers=noenddot, DIV=12]{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

% changing headers and footers
\usepackage[automark, headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ihead{\headmark}
\ohead{\pagemark}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

The rest is the intended layout, the space above the heading should be 50 per cent of the space after the footer according to traditional typographical theory.

If this is not enough for you, you may load [geometry](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) instead of `scrlayer-scrpage`, but then you may lose some functionality.

Comment: I think, it would be better to use `headinclude=true, footinclude=false`. Or use `headsepline` as class option. Then option `headinclude=true` is set automatically. Note that `geometry` can not replace `scrlayer-scrpage`. But you can load package `geometry` additionally and use its options or command `\geometry` to set the margins.

Comment: Thank you! Adding `headinclude=true` and `footinclude=true` already did a good job to move the header to the right position, but `footinclude=false` is even better. :-)

Comment: @Lilith-Elina If `footinclude=false` is better, probably depend on what you have in the footer. The header and footer should normally be part of the page calculation if they comprise of more than the page number. Nice that my answer helped you.

Comment: @Sveinung I don't have anything in the footer, so leaving it out made more sense for me.